# Stripe: send commission to "friend" when new customer subscribes using specific coupon code

Tags: stripe-payments, coupon

I have a SaaS website, where people can buy a subscription for my product. Payment is handled via Stripe.

Now I want to give a "friend" (partner/affiliate) the possibility to promote my product to THEIR audience with a stripe coupon code.

If a new customer subscribes with that coupon code, then I would like to automatically send a commission (let´s say 40% of the revenue for y months) to my friend.

The best-case scenario would be: my friend also has a stripe account and could directly see how many people signed up with the coupon code. So it would be completely transparent to him and he doesn´t have to rely on trusting me that he really gets the commission for ALL new subscribers (otherwise I could pay the commission of for instance 7 new subscribers even though there were 10).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'd like to do the same

Answer (score 0):

They would have to have a Stripe Account, and you would have to use Connect for this: https://stripe.com/docs/connect